# Convergence in $L_1$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

In order to understand a proof, I would like to understand following statement. For every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^N$:
$$
\left\| f(.+\frac{y}{m})-f \right\|_{L_1} \to 0 \mbox{ for } m \to \infty
$$
It's given that $f \in L_1$ but not that $f$ is continuous. In the proof it is said to be trivial but to me, it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use Lusin's Theorem to approximate $f$ in the $L^1$ norm by a continuous function supported on a compact set. That is, choose $g \in C^C(\mathbb{R}^N$) such that

$$\|f - g\|_{L^1} < \epsilon$$
Now use the fact that $g$ is uniformly continuous to estimate

$$\left\|f\left(x + \frac{y}{m}\right) - f(x)\right\| = \left\|f\left(x + \frac{y}{m}\right) - g\left(x + \frac{y}{m}\right) + g\left(x + \frac{y}{m}\right) - g(x) + g(x) - f(x)\right\|$$